# Trying to serve image file from S3 with API Gateway and Lambda results in corrupt file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created AWS API Gateway method which calls Lambda function which should return image file as an attachment back to user. API Gateway method is set to use Lambda Proxy Integration (requests being proxied to Lambda). My Lambda function is very simple:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();

exports.handler = async event => {
  try {
    const Bucket = event.xxx;
    const Key = event.yyy;
    const file = await s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key }).promise();

    return {
      body: file.Body.toString(),
      headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=test.jpg`,
        'Content-Length': file.ContentLength,
        'Content-Type': file.ContentType,
      },
      statusCode: 200,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

However, files downloaded this way are different in size than original ones and corrupt.

For example, I tried to upload 81264 bytes file but the downloaded version is 146650 bytes in size.
Inspecting response headers from Lambda, I see that `Content-Length` is actually `67432` (even though it's set to `file.ContentLength` which is `81264`), but there is also a custom header `x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length` which shows correct size (`81264`).

What should I do in order properly respond with correct file back?

Comment: Why not just sign a URL and redirect to it?

Comment: @Brad How do you mean exactly? I have to apply additional logic to my Lambda, and serve attachment to end user, not sure how would redirecting help in this case.

Comment: You can create a signed URL directly to the S3 bucket which instructs S3 to set your `Content-Disposition` header and all that.  And then, let S3 serve the request directly. The whole process is more efficient, and then you won't have to proxy the data.

Comment: @Brad ok, I see, but the thing is that I have to handle 2 different authorization methods (don't ask) along with some other logic before finally serving a file (e.g. finding it in a bucket based on some user identification, rename it based on some data from database, etc).

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't matter.  You leave the S3 assets as private, but then server-side you sign a URL and then S3 knows that you've authorized access.  You give it a token of sorts and the bearer of that token is permitted to access the resource.  So, do your authorization as-needed and only sign the URL when the user is authorized.  Then redirect them to it (or return it to them directly as part of an API call) and they will fetch the resource directly from S3.  S3 will know you've already authorized the user.

Comment: @Brad I understand now, and yeah, that actually might be doable! I'll have to think about it a bit more, but thanks a lot for suggestion and explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a bit more connected with general API Gateway setup, starting with defining "Binary Media Types" in API's settings (e.g. `image/jpeg`, `application/pdf`, etc.) and judging by ["API Gateway Response Content Type Conversions"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html) the request should also send `Accept` header.

Finally, I was supposed to convert `Body` to `base64`, along with adding `isBase64Encoded: true` to response, which then looks like:

```
return {
  body: file.Body.toString('base64'),
  headers: {
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=test.jpg`,
    'Content-Length': file.ContentLength,
    'Content-Type': file.ContentType,
  },
  statusCode: 200,
  isBase64Encoded: true,
};
```